# Magento CE 1.9.1 Configurable Products do not get their simple products 'associated'

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, associate-products

I have same exact problem as https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/58201/configurable-product-not-showing-in-magento.

1. Make configurable product "In Stock"
2. Use "Quick simple product creation" to generate simple products
   "enabled"  "not individually visable"  "in stock" "qty > 0"

They do not show up in "Super product attributes configuration" section

It appears that they do not get 'associated'

I have tried regenerating all indexes, flushing all caches numerous times.

Once in a while if I start from scratch, the associated products will show up, but 5 out of 6 times ... it won't work.

Comment: This happens with one attribute set that contains an added attribute "group" with 3 attributes.  All the 3 attributes are set to dropdown, use to create configurable product, global.    Magento lets me create "Quick simple product creation" from the configurable product, and I save.  The simple products are there, but are NOT associated !

Answer (score 2):

*Adding the author's comment as an answer to not leave this "unanswered":*

> This happens with one attribute set that contains an added attribute "group" with 3 attributes. All the 3 attributes are set to dropdown, use to create configurable product, global. Magento lets me create "Quick simple product creation" from the configurable product, and I save. The simple products are there, but are NOT associated !

*I am not sure if this really answers the question, but there seems to be a bug related to attribute groups*